# C# 7 Ref return on a property doesn't compile

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

While learning c# 7, I happen to stumble on *Ref return*. The *GetSingle* method below works as I learned which return me a reference outside. But *GetIns* method throws me out with a compile-time error. Unfortnately, I can't workout why and how these *GetIns* different from *GetSingle*. Can someone explain me?

**Error: An expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be return by reference.**

*Please note one of the comment was proposing this as a duplicate. But that question was type of collection and this was specifically between member of a collection and a property in a type. Hence I see this as a different question*

```
 class Pro
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var x = GetSingle(new int[] { 1, 2 });
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        static ref int GetSingle(int[] collection)
        {
            if (collection.Length > 0) return ref collection[0];
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Collection Parameter!");
        }
        static ref int GetIns(Shape s)
        {
            if (s.Area <= 0)
            {
                s.Area = 200;
                return ref s.Area;
            }
            return ref s.Area;
        }
        struct Shape {public int Area{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You can't take a `ref` of a property. `Shape.Area` is a property. The same happens if you try to pass a property to a method that accepts a `ref`/`out` parameter (like `int.TryParse("123", out s.Area)`.

Comment: [You can only return refs that are “safe to return”: Ones that were passed to you, and ones that point into fields in objects.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/). So you can return a field, not a property.

Comment: @DavidG, Thank you

Comment: `Hence I see this as a different question` - it's not about the other question being worded in the same way, it's about the fact that the answer on the other question fully answers your question too. Hence it's a duplicate.

Comment: Please do not see your question being closed as a duplicate as a bad thing. This is still a useful question as it asks a slightly different question, it's just the answer to the other one covers this question too. Someone searching SO for details on ref returns may then find yours and get directed to the other question for more answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because Shape has a **property** Area and not a public int field member. You **can not** return references to properties.

This wont compile:

```
class Shape
{
  private int mArea;

  public int Area => mArea;
}

static ref int GetIns(Shape s)
{
  if (s.Area <= 0)
  {
    s.Area = 200;
    return ref s.Area;
  }
  return ref s.Area;
}
```

But this will:

```
class Shape
{
  public int Area;
}

static ref int GetIns(Shape s)
{
  if (s.Area <= 0)
  {
    s.Area = 200;
    return ref s.Area;
  }
  return ref s.Area;
}
```

Comment: You hold true as per documentation. But you re-implemented Shape as reference type which was value type in first place. Is this mandatory  to re-implement to achieve the required result? Do you know how the same could be achieved by struct ?